# Сохранение фрагмента аудиопотока в файл

Tags: java, android

Есть код который читает аудиопоток и воспроизводит. В моем случае использую ссылку на радиоканал.

```
String DATA_STREAM = "http://online.radiorecord.ru:8101/rr_128";    
mediaPlayer = new MediaPlayer();
mediaPlayer.setDataSource(DATA_STREAM);
mediaPlayer.setAudioStreamType(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC);
mediaPlayer.setOnPreparedListener(this);
mediaPlayer.prepareAsync();
```

Теперь необходимо добавить кнопку "Начать запись" и по нажатию параллельно воспроизведению будет происходить еще и запись в файл того, что воспроизводится, до тех пор, пока не будет нажата кнопка "Закончить запись".

Подскажите как это сделать, куда копать.

Answer (score 0):

[Вот здесь](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40687840/3100967) есть готовый пример. Судя по всему, автор одновременно открывает один и тот же URL не только в `MediaPlayer`, но и в `MediaRecorder`, который начинает запись по нажатию на кнопку.

Comment: Это не то - там делают запись с микрофона, а потом её воспроизводят.